# void pointer to a struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a problem with assigning a void pointer to another struct pointer. 
My input parameter is changed inside the function semaphoreCreateBinary, but when it returns to main it is empty again. i must probably do some kind of casting but i cannot seem to get it to work.

I will include the code i think is necessary to understand my problem:

From my header file.

```
typedef struct semaphoreStruct
{
    int               smValue;  
    tcbExtS           *smHolder;  
    int               smCeiling;  
}semaS;

typedef void * SemaphoreHandle;
```

In my C file

```
unsigned int semaphoreCreateBinary(void *ro_Handle,unsigned int i_InitialValue)
{
    semaS *Semaphorehandle1;

    Semaphorehandle = malloc (sizeof(*Semaphorehandle));

    Semaphorehandle1->smValue = i_InitialValue;
    ro_Handle = Semaphorehandle1; //seems to get the correct value

    return resultUnInt;
}

int main(void)
{
    SemaphoreHandle s1vPtr;

    semaphoreCreateBinary(&s1vPtr,0);

    int IV = s1vPtr->smValue//s1vPtr is empty again here
}
```

Any suggestion how to correct this?

EDIT:
Even if i pass the argument as an adress with:
    semaphoreCreateBinary(&s1vPtr,0);
It does not work. 
I cannot change the input type since we got it from our teacher as an API-Spec otherwise i would have changed it.

Comment: You pass a void* pointer and then change the value of the pointer in the function, but the value of the pointer is a copy so the change isn't saved.  You need to pass the address to the void* pointer and then the changes will be saved.

Comment: `semaS *Semaphorehandle1; Semaphorehandle1->smValue = i_InitialValue;` will probably cause a **segfault** due to unintialised pointer variable. And, the function tries to change a *copy* of the variable passed as argument, but even so it assigns a value that will go out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: Your question is missing a description of what the code is intended to do: Should `semaphoreCreateBinary` **modify/initialize** a semaphore `struct` that is passed to it as a pointer, or should it **dynamically** allocate and initialize a new semaphore?

Comment: It should dynamically create a new semaphore and the input parameter should then point to the new semaphore when the function is finished running so i can use it in main

Comment: If you cannot use `**` then change the function type and return the pointer to allocated memory: you don't use the present return value. If you need a failure status returned, `return NULL`... and please don't change the question in response to comments and answers, it makes a nonsense of their intent when the whole question and dialog are read through.

Comment: Sorry for the edits, I can not change the function signature at all since its predefined from my teacher, thats why i posted the question otherwise i would have changed it from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
unsigned int semaphoreCreateBinary(void *ro_Handle, unsigned int i_InitialValue)
{
    semaS *Semaphorehandle1 = malloc(sizeof(semaS));
    Semaphorehandle1->smValue = i_InitialValue;
    *(semaS**)ro_Handle = Semaphorehandle1;
}

int main(void)
{
    semaS* s1vPtr;
    semaphoreCreateBinary(&s1vPtr, 1);

    int IV = s1vPtr->smValue;

    free(s1vPtr);
    printf("%d\n", IV);
}
```

Explanation: there are two important insights necessary to understand why this is a useful solution to the question - and as a future software developer you will required to gain those insights yourself:

1. In C, if you want a function to modify something, you have to pass a pointer to that something. In your case, you want to modify a `semaS*` pointer (letting it point to the newly `malloc`ed memory location). So if you want to modify a `semaS*`, you have to pass a `semaS**` to the function.
2. A `void*` can be cast to any pointer type, including a pointer **to** a pointer.

Also note that your initial `malloc` size was wrong. Since you want to allocate a new `semaS` struct, you have to `malloc` a memory block of size `size(semaS)` (you `malloc`ed a memory block the size of a pointer). Unfortunately, using any other block size will throw no compiler warnings or errors in C. But it will either waste memory (if the block size is too big) or lead to memory corruption (if the block size is too small).

Comment: Working! thank you so much! knew it was possible by casting somehow =)

Comment: It would improve the code to make the first parameter `semaS **ro_Handle` and avoid casts

Comment: @M.M the OP explained that he is not allowed to change the function signature, as that was given to him as an API interface.

Answer (score 2):

In C, arguments are passed to functions by value. So, you change only value inside a function. Also, there is another mistake: you don't allocate `Semaphorehandle1`. So, there will be segfault. This will be correct:

```
unsigned int semaphoreCreateBinary(void **ro_Handle,unsigned int i_InitialValue)
{
    semaS *Semaphorehandle1 = malloc(sizeof(semaS));
    Semaphorehandle1->smValue = i_InitialValue;
    *ro_Handle = Semaphorehandle; //seems to get the correct value
    return resultUnInt;
}
```

Don't forget to free memory after usage.

Comment: I cannot use a double pointer as input parameter since the API is specified from my teacher.

Comment: @JSmannen, you can't change value of argument without changing function signature.

Comment: This works i wanted it to but doesnt follow the API fro my teacher... Is there no other way to do it that doesnt change the without changing function signature?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, inside the `semaphoreCreateBinary()` function

```
 ro_Handle = Semaphorehandle1;
```

will not serve your purpose. The pointer `ro_Handle` *itself* is passed to the function through pass-by-value, so you cannot change the pointer itself from the function and expect it to reflect that change outside the function. You can change the value pointed by the pointer, it will sustain, but not the pointer.

In case you want to change the pointer, you need to pass the address of the pointer, as a pointer-to-pointer.

Having said that,

```
semaS *Semaphorehandle1;
Semaphorehandle1->smValue = i_InitialValue;
```

is pure wrong, as at this point, `Semaphorehandle1` is not initialized (i.e., not pointing to any valid memory location) and attempt to dereference an uninitialized pointer will lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), causing segmentation fault. You need to allocate proper memory before you can actually go ahead and dereference that pointer.

Comment: Even if i use the adress of the pointer as input semaphoreCreateBinary(&s1vPtr,0); i still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `ro_Handle = Semaphorehandle1;` will not change the value of the pointer in the `main` scope, as the pointer is a copy (passed by value) in the `semaphoreCreateBinary` scope. In order to edit the value of a pointer, you need a pointer to it:

```
unsigned int semaphoreCreateBinary(void **ro_Handle,unsigned int i_InitialValue) {
    ...
    *ro_Handle = Semaphorehandle1;
```

You then need to pass the address of your pointer to the function:

```
semaphoreCreateBinary(&s1vPtr,0);
```

Comment: I cannot use a double pointeras input parameter since the API is specified from my teacher.

Comment: This works i wanted it to but doesnt follow the API fro my teacher... Is there no other way to do it that doesnt change the without changing function signature?

Comment: No, you cannot change where `ro_handle` points without passing it by pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some serious misunderstanding about how pointers work. A pointer is a variable that **may** store the **location** of a valid variable, but does not have to - this depends on whether you correctly initialize your pointer. Your line

```
semaS *Semaphorehandle1;
```

declares an **uninitialized** pointer, i.e. a pointer that points to an arbitrary memory location. The next line

```
Semaphorehandle1->smValue = i_InitialValue;
```

then dereferences your uninitialized pointer and thus writes to an arbitrary memory locations - this is a typical memory corruption that may lead to undefined behavior for your whole program.

Comment: I did not include all my code where i allocate memory for the structure it points to in my question since i didnt think it would matter for this specific problem.

Comment: It does matter, because your code does not exhibit the behavior you intended and you are trying to find out why. The missing allocations would explain said behavior, but so do other issues. We can't know which parts of your code are wrong because your left out code by choice, and which parts are "genuinely" wrong, so we have to point out any possible issues. This will likely lead to unnecessary misunderstandings.